# Servlets, init and extends

Tags: servlets, init, extends

I'm thinking about how to create a main servlet that the rest of the servlets extends from this. I have some properties that I would like to be accesible for the whole servlets in my app and I want to init them. I think it could be something like this:

```
public abstract class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

   protected String errorURL = null;
   protected String adminMenuURL = null;
   protected String AdminLoginServlet = null;
   protected String ValidateServlet = null;

   // here, more properties and methods...

   @Override
   public void init() {
       errorURL = context.getInitParameter("errorURL");
       adminMenuURL = context.getInitParameter("adminMenuURL");
       AdminLoginServlet = context.getInitParameter("AdminLoginServlet");
       ValidateServlet = context.getInitParameter("ValidatePicsServlet");
       // here, some more inits...
   }
}
```

When I create a new Servlet like the following...

```
public class AdminLoginServlet extends MainServlet {

}
```

1. If I forward to AdminLoginServlet, would the parameters (errorURL, adminMenuURL, etc.) be assigned again?
2. If i override the init method in AdminLoginServlet (and others servlets that extends from MainServlet)... these properties won't be never assigned, isn't it?
3. How would you do what I pretend to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the members `adminMenuUrl` and so on are assigned when the servlet is first created by the engine, because this is the moment when `init()` is invoked. Every user request is handled by the same servlet instance, in different threads. When you forward a request to a servlet, the method `init()` won't be invoked.
2. you're right, because there can be no instance of `MainServlet`
3. I'm not sure how your web app should look like

You should rename the fields `AdminLoginServlet` and `ValidateServlet`, because it's bad practice to start fieldnames with upper case letters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It has been very useful for me. Regards